# encrypt data from vite react to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, encryption, vite

I am using React as frontend using vite and nodejs backend using NestJS.

we need to send data decrypted to the server, we tested this using nodejs and it's working fine and we can decrypt, but we can't use `crypto` inside vite.

```
const data = crypto.publicEncrypt(
  {
    key: publicKey,
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
    oaepHash: 'sha256',
    passphrase,
  },
  Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(json)),
);
```

Also we are using public private pem keys with pass phrase.
I also tested `crypto-js` and the encryption was fine, but we can't decrypt it.

Comment: Don't roll your own encryption. Use HTTPS. Its the industry standard for a reason.